# Вызов ошибки компиляции при невыполнении определённого условия в коде

Tags: c#, компиляция

#### Дано

Есть метод, который возвращает объект структуры Result, у которой есть поля Type (может быть равен Allowed или Disallowed) и AllowedField.
В моей задаче AllowedField не может иметь значение, если у поля Type значение Disallowed

```
public struct Result
{
    public enum Types { Allowed, Disallowed };
    public Types Type;
    private string allowedField;
}

public Result GetResult(int inputValue)
{
    Result outputObject;
    if (inputValue != 0)
    {
        outputObject.Type = Result.Types.Allowed;
        outputObject.allowedField = "12345678";
        return outputObject;
    }
    else
    {
        outputObject.Type = Result.Types.Disallowed;
        // возможно ли здесь вызывать ошибку компиляции?
        // Я не хочу случайно записать в поле allowedField какое-то значение, если у меня Type = Disallowed
        outputObject.allowedField = "12345678";
        return outputObject;
    }
}
```

#### Хотелось бы

чтобы вызывалась *ошибка подсвечивалась в IDE*, если я записываю данные в переменную, когда Type не предполагает этого.

#### Частичное решение

Можно вызывать exception, обернув поля в методы геттеры и сеттеры. Но в IDE во время просмотра кода это *как ошибка не подсвечивается*

```
public class WrongTypeException: Exception
{
    public WrongTypeException() { }
}

public struct Result
{
    Exception ResultObjectWrongType;
    public enum Types { Allowed, Disallowed };
    public Types Type;
    private string allowedField;

    public void SetAllowedField(string value) 
    {            
        if (this.Type == Types.Allowed)
        {
            this.allowedField = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new WrongTypeException();
        }
    }

    public string GetAllowedField()
    {
        if (this.Type == Types.Allowed)
        {
            return this.allowedField;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new WrongTypeException();
        }
    }
}

public Result GetResult(int inputValue)
{
    Result outputObject = new Result();
    if (inputValue != 0)
    {
        outputObject.Type = Result.Types.Allowed;
        outputObject.setAllowedField("asd");
        return outputObject;
    }
    else
    {
        outputObject.Type = Result.Types.Disallowed;
        // непозволительно
        outputObject.setAllowedField("asd");
        return outputObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не думаю, что на C# такое возможно. А так, если "непозволительно", то почему этот метод/поле там тогда существует? Делайте не `enum`, а класс, который будет описывать конкретный статус и иметь конкретные свойства/поля/методы, будет тогда что-то по типу `var outputObject = new Result<DisallowedType>(); outputObject.AllowedField  = ..; // Ошибка компиляции, DisallowedType не содержит AllowedField`, но это так, на уровне псевдокода, но суть думаю ясна.

Comment: зачем вообще здеть `Type`  тогда? Если поле allowed заполнено, значит оно allowed, если нет - то disallowed, вашими доп полями вы дублируете собственную логику.

Comment: альтернативно, вы можете сделать класс Allowed который в конструкторе принимает текст и класс Disallowed, который текст нигде не принимает. Тогда у вас просто не сможет быть Disallowed с текстом или Allowed без текста. Оба, Allowed и Disallowed наследуете от какого то интерфейса или общего класса типа IResult или Result  и радуетесь.

Comment: Вариант номер два, делаете приватный конструктор в Result и 2 метода статических CreateAllowed и CreateDisallowed, пусть эти два метода будут едиснтвенным способом создать интстанс класса Result - в них и пишите вашу логику. Все поля в этом Result обязательно делайте только для чтения, чтобы никто не мог нарушить инвариант.

Comment: Можно написать анализатор Roslyn.